# custom DownloadManager but initialization it fail

Tags: android

DownloadManager of the system is sdk 2.3,i want to use it at <2.3 device,so i copy code from source,but

i  call it :

```
public long startDownload(Uri downloadUri, boolean onlyWifi)
{

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
    request.setTitle("Test Download File"); // 
    request.setDescription("App Name");
    //request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, dirType, subPath);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/sdcard", "test.mp4");


    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

    final DownloadManager dManager = (DownloadManager)TestDownloadManager.this.getSystemService("download");
    return dManager.enqueue(request);
}
```

but it give me :

```
03-21 06:57:21.181: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(420): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 06:57:21.181: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(420):     at com.test.DownloadManager.TestDownloadManager.startDownload(TestDownloadManager.java:32)
03-21 06:57:21.181: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(420):     at com.test.DownloadManager.TestDownloadManager.onCreate(TestDownloadManager.java:16)
03-21 06:57:21.181: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(420):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
```

i post download.java at

https://gist.github.com/2145469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you simply cannot use DownloadManager on <2.3
When you call getSystemService in a devices that has API level < 9, it give you null. Thats why you are getting null pointer exception.